# NgModel call onchange function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input, onchange, angularjs-ng-model

I hava this type of code:

```
<div ng-repeat="point in points">                                
   <input type="text" ng-model="point.oy"  onchange="angular.element(this).scope().changeLocation(point.name)">
   <input type="text" ng-model="point.ox"  onchange="angular.element(this).scope().changeLocation(point.name)">
   <!--.... other inputs -->
</div>
```

What should I do to make the onchange function not run on the first bind on ng-model. 
It means that function changeLocation() should run only if user change text input.

Comment: Have you tried using `ngChange` directive? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange

Comment: No. Because ngChange run functions after each changed sign in text input.

Comment: @Fiszcz did you ever found what was the reason of that behavior?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is bind a watcher to your scope variable point in order to listen for user changes after the initialization of point. ex.

```
$scope.$watchCollection('point' , function(newPoint , oldPoint){
   //something
});
```